# Aggregation of rows based on date and value, and addition of score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have the following dataframe;

| title | date | sentiment | stock_ticker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| good news from vw | 2021-04-01 | positive | vlkaf |
| some post about vw | 2021-04-01 | positive | vlkaf |
| another post on vw | 2021-04-01 | negative | vlkaf |
| post about gme | 2020-05-01 | positive | gme |
| post about gme again | 2020-05-01 | negative | gme |
| another gme post | 2020-05-01 | negative | gme |
| more vw posts | 2021-04-02 | negative | vlkaf |
| and again vw | 2021-04-02 | negative | vlkaf |

What I'm trying to do is create a dataframe that would look like this;

| date | stock_ticker | sentiment_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | vlkaf | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | gme | -1 |
| 2021-04-02 | vlkaf | -2 |

where every time the value in the "sentiment" column is "positive", 1 gets added, and every time it's negative, 1 gets deducted from the newly created sentiment_score column. In the end, the dataframe would then be aggregated into stocks for each date and their corresponding sentiment score.

My problem however is that I would know how to do something like this in Excel, but I'm just starting out in Python and therefore have little idea of how to do something like this in there.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first `map` the column sentiment to replace positive by 1 and negative by -1, then `groupby` the two columns date and stock_ticker, `sum` and finally `reset_index` to get the expected output.

```
res = (
    df['sentiment'].map({'positive':1, 'negative':-1})
        .groupby([df['date'], df['stock_ticker']])
        .sum()
        .reset_index(name='sentiment_score')
)
print(res)
         date stock_ticker  sentiment_score
0  2020-05-01          gme               -1
1  2021-04-01        vlkaf                1
2  2021-04-02        vlkaf               -2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# look for when sentiment is positive and negative
df["sentiment_score"] = ((df["sentiment"]  == "positive").astype(int) - (df["sentiment"] == "negative").astype(int)) # True can be converted into 1
df.groupby(["date", "stock_sticker"]).sum()

#                           sentiment_score
# date       stock_sticker                 
# 2020-05-01 gme                         -1
# 2021-04-01 vlkaf                        1
# 2021-04-02 vlkaf                       -2

# input data
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ["2021-04-01", "2021-04-01", "2021-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2021-04-02", "2021-04-02"],
    "sentiment": ["positive", "positive", "negative", "positive", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative"],
    "stock_sticker": ["vlkaf", "vlkaf", "vlkaf", "gme", "gme", "gme", "vlkaf", "vlkaf"]
    })
```